# Convert XDocument to xsd file through code

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create XSD file programmatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557253/how-to-create-xsd-file-programmatically-in-c)

I have an XDocument object and I want to convert it to a xsd file through code

How am I supposed to do that?

My project looks like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Vancouver+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false"); 
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save it in `XSD` extension, if the loaded `XML` in `XDocument` object is compliant with `XSD` format.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Vancouver+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false"); 
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
// ...
doc.Save(@"C:\AnyFileName.xsd");
```

**ADDED**: Or if the `XML` is not in `XSD` format then you can generate the `XSD` based on the input `XML` using the below piece of code:

```
doc.Save(@"C:\xmlFile.xml");
string parms = @"C:\File.xml /outputdir:C:\\";
string xsdExePath = @"C:\Program Files\...\xsd.exe";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(xsdExePath, parms);
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

Now you can have your `XSD` available at C:\ drive root.

Comment: Obviously, the document posted is not an XSD...